# Implementing loop for var names for clickTags

Tags: javascript, loops, clicktag

Need to add for a banner three clickTags which have names like clickTag1, clickTag2,clickTag3. Now the code looks like this:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    document.getElementById('Destination_cta_' + i).addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.open(clickTag2, '_blank'); //here I want clickTag look like clickTag + i, but its not working.
    })
  }
```

So the question is how to loop var names so I wont need to put it manually, like it is now.

Comment: You're looking for the wonders of arrays.

Comment: But you also have the infamous loop closure bug.

Comment: any ideas how to make it better ?

Comment: Learn about arrays.

Comment: @SLaks I'm curious, what is the _loop closure bug_

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup: https://www.google.com/search?q=loop+closure+bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way to solve this problem would be to use an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

```
[, clickTag1, clickTag2, clickTag3].forEach(function(e, i) {
    document.getElementById('Destination_cta_' + i).addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.open(e, '_blank');
    })
})
```

An alternative method: if your `clickTag`s are global variables, you could always access them as global properties of the `window` object:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) (function (i) {
    document.getElementById('Destination_cta_' + i).addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.open(window['clickTag' + i], '_blank')
    })
)(i)
```

The additional wrapping function fixes the closure bug mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: `(new Array(n)).map((value, index) => { return 'clickTag' + (index + 1) })` for an array of length `n` with element `clickTag1` , `clickTag2` ... `clickTagn`

Comment: No... you're mistaking strings for variables. If you make that a dynamic window property access, it is a little closer to correct, but even then you don't know whether OP is dealing with global or local variables. Most importantly, new Array returns an array with holes, so mapping over it won't actually do anything. You still have an array of length n with no values.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use an array for this.  An array is an indexed list of values.

```
var clickTags = ["","www.nba.com","www.nhl.com","www.nfl.com"];
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    document.getElementById('Destination_cta_' + i).addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.open(clickTags[i], '_blank'); //here I want clickTag look like clickTag + i, but its not working.
    })
}
```

Notice since you are starting your loop at `1` instead of `0`, i've added a blank entry for index 0 of the `clickTags` array.

Comment: these vars has values like clickTag1 = "https://nba.com" etc. now it opens just a blank page. any ideas ?

Comment: That's because of the loop closure bug.

Comment: Either that ^^^, or see my edit, if you really don't understand arrays...

Comment: As @SLaks said, and it looks like he's correct after reading his referenced link...with this current code i've posted, all of your click events will open _www.nfl.com_.  You'll need to research the loop closure bug to fix that one.

Comment: This solution is still affected by the closure bug -- please see what I've posted below :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Why it is not currently working the way you intend :

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  // During your first loop there is a local variable `i` whose value is 1
  document.getElementById('Destination_cta_' + i)
    // Here you pass an anonymous function as the second argument to addEventListener
    // This creates a closure, which means the function's context includes variables
    // that were in scope when it was created. Right now we have the `for` loop's variable
    // `i` in the current scope, so the function keeps a *reference* to that variable.
    .addEventListener('click', function() {
     
      // When this get executed in the future, the function has to know about the variable `i`,
      // and thankfully there is a reference to it in this function's closure. But remember that
      // the for loop executed 3 times, using that same variable. That means that every function
      // was created with a closure that is keeping a reference to the same variable, whose final 
      // value after the loop finished, was 4. 
      window.alert('clickTag' + i);  // Will always alert 'clickTag4' no matter which is clicked
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="Destination_cta_1">1</div>
<div id="Destination_cta_2">2</div>
<div id="Destination_cta_3">3</div>
```

#### How to solve this problem ?

Make sure each `addEventListener` call gets a function with the correct value in a closure of its own. The way to do this is to use an immediately invoked function expression to which you pass in the value you want :

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  var element = document.getElementById('Destination_cta_' + i)

  element.addEventListener('click', (function(index) {
    // This function is now a closure with a reference to index
    return function() { 
      window.alert('clickTag' + index);
    }
  })(i)) // calling the anonymous function with the current value of `i` binds that value
         // to the function's scope
}
```

```html
<div id="Destination_cta_1">1</div>
<div id="Destination_cta_2">2</div>
<div id="Destination_cta_3">3</div>
```